# airflow errors out when trying to execute remote script through SSHHook

Tags: airflow

With airflow, I am trying to execute a remote script through SSHHook. The script is simply like this

```
echo "this is a test"
```

Inside the remote machine, I can run it through "bash test".

I created an airflow script like this:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook

# add a new SSH connection using the WEB UI under the admin --> connections tab.
sshHook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="test_ssh")

# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
    'owner': 'tester',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019,6,24),
    'email': ['user123@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('test', default_args=default_args)

t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id= sshHook,
    task_id='test_20190624',
    command='bash /home/tester/run_test',
    dag=dag)
```

Then I got an error like this:

```
[2019-06-24 11:27:17,790] {ssh_operator.py:80} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2019-06-24 11:27:17,792] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - SSH operator error: 'SSHHook' object has no attribute 'upper'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", line 82, in execute
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 90, in __init__
    conn = self.get_connection(self.ssh_conn_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 80, in get_connection
    conn = random.choice(cls.get_connections(conn_id))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 71, in get_connections
    conn = cls._get_connection_from_env(conn_id)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/base_hook.py", line 63, in _get_connection_from_env
    environment_uri = os.environ.get(CONN_ENV_PREFIX + conn_id.upper())
AttributeError: 'SSHHook' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just directly use the SSH Connection ID or just use SSHHook. The problem here is you have mixed both.

1) Using SSHHook:

```
t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_hook = sshHook,
    task_id='test_20190624',
    command='bash /home/tester/run_test',
    dag=dag)
```

2) Using SSH Connection directly:

```
t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id="test_ssh",
    task_id='test_20190624',
    command='bash /home/tester/run_test',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: I am trying to set connection from airflow to my aws ec2 linux server using ssh connection option. Normally I am able to ssh to that ec2 instance but I try Airflow ssh connection test I get

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘/Users/archanakarpe/Downloads/20-march.pem’

Comment: Path and permission works when I directly ssh to that ec2 instance.

So as https://www.cloudwalker.io/2019/09/01/airflow-connections/?unapproved=26229&moderation-hash=756f56da49cba53ccc09c482663cc961#comment-26229  airflow-connections document is saying
Note: There are a couple of catches before you jump ahead
Make sure you are able to access your Linux box from airflow server before jumping head.
Install the following python library and its dependencies
ssh_tunnel

So could someone help me how to set this ssh_tunnel in this case or is something else I am doing wrong?
Please guide me